# Can't seem to ping servers on the intranet after connecting to RRAS

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access, rras

I've setup Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard running the DNS, ADDS and RRAS roles called DC01.  I've also setup another Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard server running the Web Server roled called WEB01.

I've setup RRAS to assign from a static pool of IPs (192.168.2.200 ~ 192.168.2.220).  Once connected using the Built-in PPTP client in Windows I am properly assigned an IP.  Once connected however I can't seem to ping/connect to any servers on the LAN with the DC01 box.

The DC01 server has a public NIC and a private NIC.

Most of the configuration for RRAS is vanilla and I haven't changed very much.

How do I set RRAS up in a way that I can access servers on the LAN by IP and by DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem had to do with Hyper-V.